# Query Builder - Unknown Error Occured

Tags: sharepoint, query-builder

In Sharepoint 2013, when trying to open Query Builder windows of a Content Search Web Part, receiving an empty windows saying "Unkown error occured".

After digging in the ULS logs, a line reports the problem as:

```
    Exception in Query Builder OnLoad: 
    System.ArgumentException: An entry with the same key already exists.
```

What is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in [msdn](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/80c89831-4120-4dc2-8e1b-ad4fb7b6bf34/sharepoint-2013-query-builder-fails-to-load?forum=sharepointsearch), it is happening because of there are same named content types in parent and child sites.

To easily find the duplicates, I've used `Sharepoint Designer > Content Types` and looked for same named CTs first, then the subsites.

After finding the problematic ones and renaming/deleting, problem solved.

Comment: nice one, this helped me. Thanks!

Comment: I am having the same issue, but it doesn't appear to be the Content Type issue.

ULS logs show: 
Exception in Query Builder OnLoad: Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException: List does not exist.  The page you selected contains a list that does not exist.  It may have been deleted by another user. ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: List does not exist.  The page you selected contains a list that does not exist.  It may have been deleted by another user.

Answer (score 1):

Quite often to answer to this issue is making sure that the user attempting to use the Query Builder is an administrator on the search service application.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also having the same issue, and definitely not attributed to duplicate content types.

I've set up a service application farm for crawling multiple resources.  This farm's only web application is Central Admin.  I've tried rebuilding the Search Service Applications to no avail.  I'm seeing a endpoint failure while attempting to access published services across farms., immediately followed by the Query Builder OnLoad exception.

The Exception in Query Builder OnLoad:

Exception in Query Builder OnLoad:System.ServiceModel.FaultException `1[System.ServiceModel.ExceptionDetail]: Attempted to perform an unauthorized operation. (Fault Detail is equal to An Exception Detail, likely created by IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults=true, whose value is: System.UnauthrozedException:  Attempted to perform an unauthorized operation.  at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.Ranking.GetRankingModels()  at SyncInvokeGetRankingModels...etc etc etc.

The "unauthorized" made me think that I might have missed permissions somewhere on the Service Application, but after checking, everything was in order.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error (more specifically, in the ULS it mentioned it couldn't find a list, no specific listname, just that) and it turned out to be the current language setting. I changed it to English and it started working again. After building the query, changed the language back and all was fine. Not the way things should be but there you go.